# ODBC from QlikView to SQL fails on *first attempt*

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, qlikview

I am running an ODBC from my QlikView server to SQL server to read some data. Every time I run the task that starts the reading it fails at the first attempt. When I run it the second time, it connects and works. Any ideas?

Qlikview log error:

> (12/29/2019 12:34:11 PM) Error: The task
>   "Kontroller_Prod_conector/2_DW_SBO_Connector.qvw" failed. Exception:
>   || QDSMain.Exceptions.TaskFailedException: Task execution failed with
>   errors to follow. ---> QDSMain.Exceptions.ReloadFailedException:
>   Reload failed ---> QDSMain.Exceptions.LogBucketErrorException: The
>   Source Document was NOT reloaded successfully.
>   DocumentPath=C:\KONTROLLER\KONTROLLERQV_PROD\4_APPLICATION\2_DW_SBO_Connector.qvw.  ||    at
>   QDSMain.AbstractReloadTask.VerifyConditions(IExecutingTaskResult
>   executingTaskResult) ||    at QDSMain.AbstractReloadTask.Reload(String
>   fileName, IExecutingTaskResult executingTaskResult, String
>   sectionAccessUserName, String sectionAccessPassword, eReloadOptions
>   reloadOption, String variableName, String variableValue, Boolean
>   moniterCpuUsage) ||    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ||
>   at QDSMain.AbstractReloadTask.Reload(String fileName,
>   IExecutingTaskResult executingTaskResult, String
>   sectionAccessUserName, String sectionAccessPassword, eReloadOptions
>   reloadOption, String variableName, String variableValue, Boolean
>   moniterCpuUsage) ||    at
>   QDSMain.DistributeTask.PerformExecute(IExecutingTaskResult
>   executingTaskResult) ||    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ||    at QDSMain.DistributeTask.PerformExecute(IExecutingTaskResult
>   executingTaskResult) ||    at
>   QDSMain.Task.AbstractTask.TaskExecution(CurrentExecutionArgs args)
>
> (12/29/2019 12:34:11 PM) Information: Task Execute
>   Duration=00:00:06.3916864
>
> (12/29/2019 12:34:11 PM) Information: TaskResult.status=Finished

Screen shot from QlikView

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you `Ctrl+e` and access the stript, you may need to change the database from ODBC to OLE-DB

[image: Edit script window of qlikview file]

Using the Connect and Select buttons here you can try and manually connect to the database.